# A problem with margin-top property in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I made a HTML webpage, and it gave me this.
[image]
The structure is as follows (the accompanying CSS code is given below this one)

```
<header>
<h1></h1>
</header>
<section>
<article id="article1"></article>
<article id="article2"></article>
</section>
<section>
<article id="article3"></article>
</section>
```

The CSS code is this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

header {
  background-color: #6699ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 700px;
  clear: both;
}

article {
  background-color: #99ffff;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #6699ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#article1 {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
  height: 250px;
}

#article2 {
  float: right;
  width: 320px;
  height: 250px;
}

#article3 {
  width: 680px;
}
```

So I wanted to separate the two articles on top from the one on the bottom, and tried this:

```
<header>
<h1></h1>
</header>
<section>
<article id="article1"></article>
<article id="article2"></article>
</section>
<section style="margin-top: 10px">
<article id="article3"></article>
</section>
```

But I am getting the same result. I know what margin collapses are but this doesn't seem to be that. Can you please help me fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that allows us to help you. Share your code that shows the problem.

Comment: I did show the code I used, tho. It's just that for some example the margin is not being applied.

Comment: Okay lemme just give you the CSS code for this

Comment: try to put all your css, html into the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the first `section` which only contains floated elements (i.e. the first two articles). Those will not be "wrapped" by the section's borders by default, so that section will therefore have a height of zero (use the browser tools to see that...), eventually causing the shown behaviour.

To avoid that, add `overflow: auto;` to the sections, or at least to those sections which only contain floated elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

header {
  background-color: #6699ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 700px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

article {
  background-color: #99ffff;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #6699ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#article1 {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
  height: 250px;
}

#article2 {
  float: right;
  width: 320px;
  height: 250px;
}

#article3 {
  width: 680px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1></h1>
</header>
<section>
  <article id="article1">blabla</article>
  <article id="article2">blabla</article>
</section>
<section style="margin-top: 10px">
  <article id="article3">blabla</article>
</section>
```